# discord.js bot don't see direct messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I decided to make a discord bot on node.js, and i found that library `dicord.js`. I want to make a bot receive direct message from users, but for some reason it don't see messages that were sent directly to him.

Version of `discord.js`:

```
npm view discord.js version
14.9.0
```

Version of `node` and `npm`:

```
node -v                    
v18.15.0
```

```
npm -v
9.5.0
```

Here's my code:

```
import discord from 'discord.js';
import config from './config.js';

const bot = new discord.Client({intents: config.intents, partials: config.partials})
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});

bot.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});

bot.login(config.token);
```

And my `config.js` file:

```
import discord from 'discord.js'
const { GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = discord

export default {
    "token": xxxxxxx,
    "intents": Object.keys(GatewayIntentBits),
    "partials": [Object.keys(Partials)]
}
```

So yeah, i literally gave him all the intents and partials, just to make sure i didn't miss some. I expect to see something like this in console when i send message to him in direct:

```
<ref *1> Message {
  channelId: '1101904091908689970',
  guildId: '1101895271669055611',
  id: '1102197229973938348',
  createdTimestamp: 1682854697460,
  type: 0,
  system: false,
  content: 'Hello',
  author: User {
    id: 'xxxxxxxx',
    bot: false,
    system: false,
    flags: UserFlagsBitField { bitfield: 0 },
    username: 'sewrprvrt',
    discriminator: 'xxxx',
    avatar: '49891ad2803d523d6edf79dd41b72ecb',
    banner: undefined,
    accentColor: undefined
  },
  pinned: false,
  tts: false,
  nonce: '1102197239196942336',
  embeds: [],
  components: [],
  attachments: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  stickers: Collection(0) [Map] {},
  position: null,
  roleSubscriptionData: null,
  editedTimestamp: null,
  reactions: ReactionManager { message: [Circular *1] },
  mentions: MessageMentions {
    everyone: false,
    users: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    roles: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    _members: null,
    _channels: null,
    _parsedUsers: null,
    crosspostedChannels: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    repliedUser: null
  },
  webhookId: null,
  groupActivityApplication: null,
  applicationId: null,
  activity: null,
  flags: MessageFlagsBitField { bitfield: 0 },
  reference: null,
  interaction: null
}
```

So how i said i tried to check all intents and partials, but that didn't work. I searched the internet to find out how to fix it, but everything I found didn't help me either. Probably because discord.js updated to 14 version recently i didn't find a working option for me.

I would really appreciate it if anyone knows where i screwed up, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`<user>.createDM()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) in order for discord.js to fire `messageCreate` events for that user's DMs. You have to do this for each user you want to get DMs from, and do it again if your bot restarts.

I'm not sure why it works like this, but I assume it has something to do with caching only the DM channels you actually need, instead of caching every single DM channel for every user your bot can see (which can get to the millions really fast).

If you'd like your users to be able to interact with your bot through DMs without having to do this, I recommend looking into using [Application Commands](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands), as those fire interaction events regardless of you having `.createDM`'d